# I want to limit user to enter space after text in jquery and will remove the space if it after text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below's code will replace space with '-', so if the user input a lot of space after text, it will be like 'apple---------'. Therefore, I want to limit user enter one space after the text, it will be apple- and will not accept anymore space but only text, e.g. apple-red but not apple--- or apple--red. 
if the user submit the text and if space after the text, I want to know how to remove the space either? Thanks!

```js
     var $input = $('#tag'); 
     $input.val(function(_,v){
return v.replace(/\s+/g,'-');
 
     
     });// '-'repace space
```

```html
<input type="text" id="tag" />
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

This would be a lot easier, and my gut says a lot faster too.   Use trim, then add your "-" if you really need it.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But how can I limit user enter only one space after the text but user still can enter text?